# How can I get a thumbnail from a movie without playback starting Monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage, mpmovieplayercontroller

I would like to eliminate the `movie.Stop()` lines from my code.

What other method could I use to obtain a thumbnail from the movie?

```
NSUrl data = new NSUrl(info.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL")).ToString());

//get the video thumbnail
MPMoviePlayerController movie = new MPMoviePlayerController(data);
movie.Stop();
UIImage videoThumbnail = movie.ThumbnailImageAt(0.0, MPMovieTimeOption.NearestKeyFrame);
movie.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run code like the following and it seems to work just fine in an app I wrote.  Note the ShouldAutoplay=false;

```
NSUrl data = new NSUrl(info.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL")).ToString());

//get the video thumbnail
MPMoviePlayerController movie = new MPMoviePlayerController(data);
movie.ShouldAutoplay = false;
UIImage videoThumbnail = movie.ThumbnailImageAt(0.0, MPMovieTimeOption.NearestKeyFrame);
```